# imakeidx problem when compiled using Texniccenter

Tags: indexing, texniccenter, imakeidx

I am using `imakeidx` to customize my index of my thesis. I tried looking for the solution but the nearest I can get is more or less similar question posted by one of the user in this community, pyro. I tried compiling the following script but failed to get the desired outcome. I have included `pyro.ist` file in my working folder which contain the following command:

```
heading_prefix "\n\\noindent\\textbf{"
heading_suffix "}\\par\\nopagebreak\n"
headings_flag 1
```

All my `.idx`, `.ilg` and `.ind` files were successfully compiled but not the final outcome. I am using TeXnicCenter and MiKTeX. Is it something to do with my TeXnicCenter setting? Please help.

The script is as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper,twoside]{extbook}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\makeindex[program=makeindex,options=-s pyro,columns=2,intoc=true]

\begin{document}  
\tableofcontents
\chapter{This is the First Chapter}  

She was angry \index{angry}  that she wasn't given an apple\index{apple}.  
He drank some beer \index{beer} and then played ball \index{ball}.  

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: not relevant to the question, but if you leave a space between the word in text and the `\index` command, the spacing in your output will be uneven.  although tex compresses multiple spaces, if there's something in between those spaces, they are handled separately.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't tell us the version of MiKTeX you use.  And so we do not know which package versions you are using in your system.

With an current MiKTeX (`pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)`) I can compile your code without any errors or warnings (except the one warning about `filecontents` that I only used to have one compiling MWE with tex code and `ist` file).

I also used the current version TeXnicCenter (2.02 Stable). In TeXnicCenter you need to have the following parameters set to be able to run `makeindex` through TeXnicCenter:

[image: parameter for makeindex in TeXnicCenter]

Please see that I'm using `%tm`.  I guess you will have `%bm` there (old version).

With this parameters I can run the follwing MWE (for example `277392.tex`):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{pyro.ist}
heading_prefix "\n\\noindent\\textbf{"
heading_suffix "}\\par\\nopagebreak\n"
headings_flag 1
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[11pt,a5paper,twoside]{extbook}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\makeindex[program=makeindex,options=-s pyro,columns=2,intoc=true]

\begin{document}  
\tableofcontents
\chapter{This is the First Chapter}  

She was angry\index{angry}  that she wasn't given an apple\index{apple}.  
He drank some beer\index{beer} and then played ball\index{ball}.  

\printindex

\end{document}
```

with the result (only index page):

[image: result of index page]

In the resulting log file you should see at the end of it the following message:

```
Chapter 1.
[3] [4

]
runsystem(makeindex -s pyro 277392.idx)...executed (allowed).
```

Then you know the index is prepared to be included in your document (another run is needed!)